# RavenDB - using "Analyzers" in "Dynamic Query"

Tags: ravendb

This is contrary to another post I asked about how to NOT use dynamic queries, but in preparation for the thought that I may need to, I am attempting to learn more.

I have situations where **sometimes** I want a field to be analyzed, and sometimes I do not. I am solving this right now by having two separate indexes.

```
/// <summary>
/// Query for an entity by its identity or name, using full indexing to search for specific parts of either.
/// </summary>
public class [ENTITY]__ByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<[ENTITY]> {
    public [ENTITY]__ByName() {
        Map = results => from result in results
                         select new {
                             Id = result.Id,
                             Name = result.Name
                         };

        Index(n => n.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Query for an entity by its full name, or full identity without any analyzed results, forcing
/// all matches to be absolutely identical.
/// </summary>
public class [ENTITY]__ByFullName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<[ENTITY]> {
    public [ENTITY]__ByFullName() {
        Map = results => from result in results
                         select new {
                             Id = result.Id,
                             Name = result.Name
                         };
    }
}
```

However, I am being told that I should be using "dynamic indexes" *(which to me defeats the purpose of having indexes, but this comment came from a senior developer that I greatly respect, so I am entertaining it)*

So, I need to figure out how to pass my preference in analyzer to a dynamic query. Right now  my query looks something along the lines of ...

```
RavenQueryStatistics statistics;

var query = RavenSession
    .Query<[ENTITY], [INDEX]>()
    .Customize(c => c.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
    .Statistics(out statistics)
    .Search(r => r.Name, [name variable])
    .Skip((request.page - 1) * request.PageSize)
    .Take(request.PageSize)
    .ToList();

var totalResults = statistics.TotalResults;
```

Alright, so since I am informed having so many indexes isn't what I should do, I need to go to dynamic queries? So it would be more like this ... ?

```
RavenQueryStatistics statistics;

var query = RavenSession
    .Query<[ENTITY]>()
    .Customize(c => c.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
    .Statistics(out statistics)
    .Search(r => r.Name, [name variable])
    .Skip((request.page - 1) * request.PageSize)
    .Take(request.PageSize)
    .ToList();

var totalResults = statistics.TotalResults;
```

But the problem is that sometimes I want an `Analyzer` - and sometimes I don't. For example...

On a grid of 6000 results, if the user does a "search" for `One`, I want it to find everything that has `One` *anywhere* in the name. The analyzer allows for this.

On a **validator** that is designed to ensure that the user does not add a new entity with the exact same name as another, I do not want such flexibility. If the user is typing in `Item Number` as the name, and `Item Number 2` exists, I do not want it to match because one or two of the words match. I want it to match if they type in **exactly** the same word.

So, is there a way to incorporate this into `dynamic` queries? or am I smart to just keep using different queries?

Comment: Just to confirm; you want to choose the analyzer at runtime (analyzed vs not-analyzed), and not as part of the definition of a static index? Analyzed indexes will provide what you want (splits words apart for searching), so you don't really need both analyzed and not analyzed defined, as analyzed is more intensive and therefore more flexible.